# Determining time complexity of a specific function

Tags: c, time-complexity

This is a question from one of the old exams from algorithms and data structure that I recently came upon. I'm having a hard time understanding the solution.
I need to find `big-O`, `big-ϴ` and `big-Ω` bounds of a function:

```
void recursion(int n) {
 int i;
 if (n == 0) {
 return;
 }
 for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
 recursion(i);
 }
}
```

The solution is `2^n` for all three and I can't understand why. I've tried writing things down and I can't even get close to the solution. I would appreciate if anyone would explain where the `2^n` comes from here.

Comment: Perhaps observing the difference between the calls `recursion(2)` and `recursion(3)` will help you.

Comment: Isn't the recursion unbounded here?

Comment: @information_interchange: No. Each recursive call within a call to `recursion(n)` is passed a parameter less than `n`.

Comment: Ah yes, I see now; the `i<n` is almost  like an `n-1`. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's look at a simpler recursion which is known to be O(2^n)

```
void fib(int n) {
    if (n < 3) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2);
    }
}
```

Here you can see, for the non-trivial case of n > 2, this will result in 2^(n-2) calls to itself.  For example, if n = 5:

```
n = 5
    n = 4
        n = 3
            n = 2
            n = 1
        n = 2
    n = 3
        n = 2
        n = 1
```

There are 8 (2^3) recursive calls, because each call with n > 2 spawns two more recursive calls, so fib(n+1) has twice as many recursive calls as fib(n).

So for your example:

```
n = 3
    n = 2
        n = 1
            n = 0
        n = 0
    n = 1
        n = 0
    n = 0
```

so we get 7 recursive calls when n = 3

for n = 4

```
n = 4
    n = 3
        n = 2
            n = 1
                n = 0
            n = 0
        n = 1
            n = 0
        n = 0
    n = 2
        n = 1
            n = 0
        n = 0
    n = 1
        n = 0
    n = 0
```

Here, we have 15 calls.  Looking at the execution tree above, you can see that recusrsion(4) is basically recursion(3) + recursion(3) + 1

```
n = 4
    n = 3          // + 1
        n = 2                //
            n = 1            //
                n = 0        // recursion(3)
            n = 0            //
        n = 1                //
            n = 0            //
        n = 0                //
    n = 2           //
        n = 1       //
            n = 0   // recursion(3)
        n = 0       //
    n = 1           //
        n = 0       //
    n = 0           //
```

So in general, recursion(n + 1) will have one more recursive calls than 2 * recursion(n)....which is basically doubling for every +1 to n....which is O(2^n)

Comment: The naive recursive computation of Fibonacci is not Φ(2^n). It's Φ(ψ^n) where ψ is (sqrt(5)+1)/2, approximately 1.618. In other words, it's Φ(fib(n)), which is clear from the recursion itself. OP's recursion really is Φ(2^n), but your answer skirts around a sumple proof of this fact.

Answer (score 2):

Since this smells like a homework question, this answer is incomplete by design.

The usual trick behind these kind of problems is to create a recurrence equation. That is, the time complexity of `recursion(k+1)` is somehow related to the complexity of `recursion(k)`. Just writing down the recurrence itself is not sufficient to prove the complexity, you have to demonstrate why the recurrence is true. But, for 2<sup>n</sup>, this suggests that `recursion(k+1)` takes twice as long as `recursion(k)`.

> Let T(k) denote the time complexity of `recursion(k)`. Since `recursion(0)` returns immediately, let T(0) = 1. For k > 0, given the iterative implementation of `recursion`
>      [image: T(k) = Σ T(i) for 0 ≤ i < k]
> Thus
>      [image: T(k+1) = Σ T(i) for 0 ≤ i < k+1]
> [image: → T(k+1) = T(k) + Σ T(i) for 0 ≤ i < k]
> [image: → T(k+1) = T(k) + T(k) = 2 × T(k)]
> You can inductively prove that T(k) = 2<sup>k</sup>.

Answer (score 2):

Let's denote the total runtime as `f(n)`. Due to the loop in the function the `f(n)` is actually a sum of `f(i)` for `i` between 0 and n-1. That's a sum of `n` items. Let's try to simplify the expression. A standard trick in such situations is to find a complimentary equation. Let's see what is the value of `f(n-1)`. Similary to the previous case, it's a sum of `f(i)` for `i` between 0 and n-2. So now we have 2 equations:

```
f(n)=f(1)+...+f(n-1)
f(n-1)=f(1)+...+f(n-2)
```

Let's subtract second from the first:

```
f(n)-f(n-1)=f(n-1)
--> f(n)=2f(n-1)
```

Now this is a [homogeneous linear recurrence relation with constant coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Solving_homogeneous_linear_recurrence_relations_with_constant_coefficients).
The solution is immediate (see the link for more details):

**f(n)=f(1)*2<sup>n</sup>=2<sup>n</sup>**

Answer (score 1):

```
r(n)   = r(n-1)+r(n-2)+...+r(0) // n calls.
r(n-1) = r(n-2)+r(n-3)+...+r(0) // n-1 calls.
r(n-2) = r(n-3)+r(n-4)+...+r(0) // n-2 calls.
.
.
.
r(1)   = r(0)                   // 1 call.
r(0)   = return;                // 0 call.
```

So,

```
r(n)   = r(n-1)+r(n-2)+...+r(0)         // n calls.
       = 2 * (r(n-2)+...+r(0))          // 2 * (n - 1) calls.
       = 2 * ( 2 * (r(n-3)+...+r(0)) )  // 2 * 2 * (n - 2) calls.
.
.
.
```

This follows that =>

```
2^(n-1) * (n - (n-1))
```

And that would be

```
2^n calls...
```